# Progress bar com JQuery contando negativo

Tags: php, upload

Olá, eu uso esse código para aumentar a barra de progresso:

```
$(function() 
{
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    var upload = $('form').ajaxForm(
    {
        beforeSend: function() 
        {
            status.empty();
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
        {          
            document.getElementById("progressBarCurrentFile").style.display = 'block';
            var total_perc = total | 0;
            var current_perc = position | 0;
            document.getElementById("progbarFile").innerHTML = Math.floor((current_perc / (total_perc / 100)) * 100) / 100 + '%';
            document.getElementById("progbarFile").style.width = current_perc / (total_perc / 100) + '%';
        },
        complete: function(xhr) 
        {
            location.href = 'home';
        }
    });
});
```

O problema é que quando o arquivo é maior que `2GB` ele começa a contar negativo.

Mesmo eu colocando no pho.ini `post_max_size = 9999999M` e `upload_max_filesize = 9999999M`

Comment: Você consegue saber o tamanho do arquivo antes de mandar, correto? Quando termina de subir, ele dá o tamanho certinho ou entra nesse número negativo? Digo, o tamanho final fica menor que o original?

Comment: @Daniel Sim, ele chega sem nenhuma perda.

Comment: Então não é só considerar esse número negativo como 0? Daí você faz proporcional para 100% com o tamanho do arquivo, dá na mesma.

Comment: @Daniel Não, por que tem vezes que ele chega a -340%.

Comment: Então, pega o primeiro valor quer chegar para ``current_perc`` e usa ele como valor mínimo. Você pode inclusive reduzir esse valor de total na sua conta em todas as outras operações. ``(current_perc / ((total_perc - minimal_perc) / 100)) * 100) / 100 + '%'``, sacou?

Answer (score 0):

Minha ideia: você guarda o primeiro valor que chegar o servidor como valor corrente e usa ele como se fosse o seu 0.

$(function() 
{
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');
    var first_val, minimal_perc;

```
var upload = $('form').ajaxForm(
{
    beforeSend: function() 
    {
        first_val = true;
        status.empty();
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
    {          
        document.getElementById("progressBarCurrentFile").style.display = 'block';
        if (first_val) { 
          minimal_perc = position; 
          first_val = false;
        };
        var total_perc = total | 0;
        var current_perc = position | 0;

        if (current_perc < 0) total_perc -= minimal_perc;

        document.getElementById("progbarFile").innerHTML = Math.floor((current_perc / (total_perc / 100)) * 100) / 100 + '%';
        document.getElementById("progbarFile").style.width = current_perc / (total_perc / 100) + '%';
    },
    complete: function(xhr) 
    {
        location.href = 'home';
    }
});
```

Comment: Mesmo usando seu código, continua com valores como -147%.

Comment: Estranho, por que é apenas com arquivos com 2GB ou mais.

Comment: Deve ser alguma característica do ``HTTP`` que eu desconheço.